# Adding row in excel file in someone else's onedrive

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I have to add a row in excel file in a onedrive business account. I tried the following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-write-to-workbook and it worked for the file which was in my own onedrive.
However when I tried the following POST request with the correct drive and Item Id I keep getting 403 Forbidden error. It also doesn't show what all permissions are exactly required to do the same. This is the URL I tried for POST request [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-Id}/items/{Item-Id}/workbook/tables/Table2/rows/add](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-Id%7D/items/%7BItem-Id%7D/workbook/tables/Table2/rows/add) I keep getting following response
[Response I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21GHv.png)

[It doesn't show what permissions are actually required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w6G6.png)

Comment: has the file been shared with you with Edit permissions? If not, you won't be able to manipulate it.

Comment: @teylyn yeah it's shared with me with edit permission, even then I can't edit